# How to create a floor plan map on xcode?

Tags: xcode, dictionary, frameworks, location

I would like to know how to make a floor plan map on xcode.

floor plan example:
http://www.asiaislandhomes.com/developments/suriyana/images/lower_floor_plan.jpg

Where the app would be able to
locate where the user is on that floor and would be able to tell the user where the entrances, exits are. Also, the user will be able to search where the bathroom and bedroom is.

Comment: This question is too broad - you're asking for an entire app. And most phone location services don't really work too accurately indoors, so the whole premise may be flawed anyway.

Comment: @tanya have you got the solution...i am also trying to develop a floor plan for a exhibition area..

Comment: @TanyaLertwichaiworawit for showing the entrance, bedrooms and bathrooms you can statically added some notation over the floorPlan Image but for locating the user on floor plan i think you have to creating  your own navigation. Study the cocos 2D CCTileMap on which you draw the floorPlan.

Comment: @RaviSharma Yes I know that but still you'll need to create the wifi trilateration for this which is not easy.